# oracle sql database linkage and python plotly dashboard graph visualization

Tags: python, oracle, plotly, plotly-dash

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import os
from sqlite3 import connect
import sqlalchemy

os.putenv('NLS_LANG', '.UTF8')

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost', 1521, 'xe')
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('dbid', 'dbpw', dsn)


cursor = db_conn.cursor()
# cursor.execute('select a, b from tablename')

query = 'select a, b from tablename'

#row = cursor.fetchall()
#df = pd.DataFrame(row)                  

df = pd.read_sql(query, db_conn)
df.index = list(df[0]) # category
df.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')
print(df)

'''
app = dash.Dash() 

# Creating DATA
random_x = pd.read_sql('category', db_conn)
random_y = pd.read_sql('fee', db_conn)

#random_x = np.random.randint(1, 101, 100)
#random_y = np.random.randint(1, 101, 100)

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='scatterplot',
                                 figure={'data':[go.Scatter(
                                     x=random_x,
                                     y=random_y,
                                     mode='markers',
                                     marker={
                                         'size':12,
                                         'color':'rgb(51,204,153)',
                                         'symbol':'pentagon',
                                         'line':{'width':2}
                                     }
                                 )],
                                         'layout':go.Layout(title='My Scatterplot',
                                                            xaxis={'title':'Some X title'})}
                                 ),
                        dcc.Graph(id='scatterplot2',
                                 figure={'data':[go.Scatter(
                                     x=random_x,
                                     y=random_y,
                                     mode='markers',
                                     marker={
                                         'size':12,
                                         'color':'rgb(200,204,53)',
                                         'symbol':'pentagon',
                                         'line':{'width':2}
                                     }
                                 )],
                                         'layout':go.Layout(title='Second Plot',
                                                            xaxis={'title':'Some X title'})}
                                 )
                       ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()'''
```

I am trying to connect oracle sql database and visualize python plotly dashboard graph.

I've tried several lectures and Googling, but it's hard to find an answer than I thought, so I'm asking this question.

Is it possible to visualize a bar graph in a form similar to a dashboard by applying oracle sql db data?

Comment: I'll let a ploty or dash expert answer.  From the Oracle side you just need data in whatever format they require.  That should be simple once you can plot, for example, some fixed data values.  Unrelated: (1) use keyword arguments when connecting. This is mandatory in the latest driver (2) Setting the char set with NLS_LANG isn't useful in recent cx_Oracle because UTF-8 is always used.
(3) use the latest driver, which got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that may get you going.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import cx_Oracle as oracledb
import platform
import os

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")
elif platform.system() == "Windows":
     oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_14")

username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
connect_string = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")

connection = oracledb.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=connect_string)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:

    cursor.execute("""
        begin
          begin
            execute immediate 'drop table mytab';
            exception when others then
              if sqlcode <> -942 then
                raise;
              end if;
          end;

          execute immediate 'create table mytab (id number, data number)';

          insert into mytab (id, data) values (1, 10);
          insert into mytab (id, data) values (2, 4);
          insert into mytab (id, data) values (3, 34);
          insert into mytab (id, data) values (4, 12);
          insert into mytab (id, data) values (7, 9);
        end;""")

    y = []
    for v, in cursor.execute("select data from mytab order by id"):
        y.append(v)


print("Plot is:")
x = list(range(1, len(y)+1))
#plt.xticks(x)                         # for points
#plt.plot(x, y, "o", label="My data")  # for points
plt.bar(x, y, label="My data")         # for bars
plt.xlabel('Row number')
plt.ylabel('Data value')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

Output is like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep that in mind.
Is it difficult to implement a dashboard by modifying my code?